# Vuex value assignment from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I download data from firebase realtime database to my vuex store, using this code.

```
 firebase.database().ref('Profiles').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once('value')
  .then((data) => {
    var obj = data.val()
    console.log("DATA.VAL().votedQuests", data.val().votedQuests)
    const profile = {
      id: obj.id,
      votedQuests: data.val().votedQuests,
    }
```

In result under data.val().votedQuests i got:

```
console print:
    DATA.VAL().votedQuests: -M3pc4Bf4bSjqeSw1CvB: "Tak"
```

what is correct:

[image: screen: data structure from firebase]

BUT when i do this:

```
const profile = {
      id: obj.id,
      votedQuests: data.val().votedQuests,
    }
```

or

```
const profile = {
      id: obj.id,
      votedQuests: obj.votedQuests,
    }
```

and try to print result in console.log("Profile",profile), i got this view:

```
console print:
votedQuests: Object
         -M3pc4Bf4bSjqeSw1CvB: "Tak"
         rbFeBq6lckgH7k1KZr419Gz9cGJ3: undefined //this key rbFeB... is uid of user. It should not be here.
```

Could you explain to me why this key `rbFeBq6lckgH7k1KZr419Gz9cGJ3: undefined` is under my votedQuests where in firebase it's not there ?

What is more when I check  `obj.votedQuests` value before `const profile{...}` it's correct.

Comment: Did you try console logging `obj`?
what does that print?

Comment: Can you show **where** you use `console.log("Profile",profile)` in relation to the `.once('value')
  .then((data) => {` that you already shared?

Comment: I use `console.log("Profile",profile)` after `const profile{...}` statement in `data` promise. When i use `console.log(obj)` before `const profile {...}` statement, object is correcct